# React - Best practice for pages with lots of static data?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I've just started working with React and I'm building a page that has a lot of static content. I'm wondering if there are any best practices to do this? After speaking to a friend he's told me it's better to wrap each segment of this static page into separate components, but I really don't see the advantage to doing so as the content isn't dynamic.

Is there good practice for handling large amounts of static content? This is currently a component within a page folder.

```
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <Navigation/> {/* Main Header */}
            <Jumbotron>
                <h1>Example Header</h1>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
                    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
                <img src="placeholder.it/100" className="header__down-arrow" alt="Down Arrow"/>
            </Jumbotron>

            {/* Content Block 1 */}
            <TextBlock className="textBlock">
                <h2>Intro Title Here</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
                    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                    consequat.
                </p>
                <p>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore
                    eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt
                    in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>
            </TextBlock>

            {/* Content Block 2 */}
            <TextBlock className="textBlock--yellow">
                <h2>Example Header</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
                    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                    consequat.
                </p>
                <p>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore
                    eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt
                    in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>

                {/* Terms and conditions */}
                <TermsConditions>
                    <p>Click Here to view Terms and Conditions</p>
                </TermsConditions>

            </TextBlock>
            <Footer/>

        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Best practices say: **Divide and Conquer!!!** I would suggest to use `PureComponent`, which are components with a default implementation of `componentShouldUpdate`. In the example you've provided, that does not make any sense. But in a real case you would end up with a huge component that, sooner or later, will become unmanageable.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider storing the static content in separate files that are read in before the page renders (json, plaintext, markdown, etc.). This would make it easier to separate the actual information from the way it's presented.